# How to make 2D-Array (Take Pixel-Colors from Frame)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am new to python and I need an array like this (2D):

```
a = np.array([[161, 141, 129],
              [161, 141, 129],
              [162, 142, 130],
              [170, 168, 187],
              [165, 169, 182]])
```

And I do have an array like this:

```
array([[[161, 141, 129],
    [161, 141, 129],
    [162, 142, 130],
    ...,
    [170, 168, 187],
    [165, 169, 182],
    [165, 169, 182]],

   [[171, 143, 134],
    ...,
    [162, 169, 187]],
   ...,
   [[ 55,  29,  41],
    ...,
    [ 64,   7,   0]]], dtype=uint8)
```

I read something about shaping an array, but I don't get it working.
How can I get a new 2D Array out of this?

The source-array has the shape 640x480x3 (X-Axis, Y-Axis, RGB-Color)
Any help is appreciated.

Target is to have all RGB-Values in a 2D-Array, so that I can call scipy.spatial.distance.cdist with this values.

Comment: And what is the logic for getting from one to the other??

Comment: So you simply want to slice the array, i.e. `a[:,:,0]` and so on?

Comment: You can need to either select or combine the dimensions in some way.  E.g., if you want to sum the colors over the last dimension you can do `arr.sum(2)` to your `640x480x3` array and get out `640x480` array (or if you want the average `avg = arr.sum(2)/3`).  Or you can just select a specific color like the red image is `arr[:,:,0]`, green is `arr[:,:1]`, blue is `arr[:,:,2]`.

Comment: Answers do not match yet. So what do I need to write to get a 2D Array with all color informations?

Comment: @yatu: Please remove your duplicate-question-mark. I have found the correct solution and want to answer this here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution:

```
a = a.reshape(1,-1)
a = a.reshape(int(len(a[0])/3),-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

the red is a[:,:,0]
Green is a[:,:,1]
Etc